# Create nested object of booleans, arrays and objects from array

Tags: javascript, object, logic, reduce

I am trying to create an object to satisfy the structure required by [json-logic-js](https://jsonlogic.com/). An example of that structure is provided below.

The source array is made up of `booleans` and `strings`. Strings can only be `OR`, `AND`, `NAND` or `NOR`. For now am I working only with `OR` and `AND`.

The array of booleans and strings might look like the below. The values are dynamic. So the booleans can be either true or false and strings as mentioned above.

```
const source = [false, "OR", false, "OR", false, "AND", false, "AND", false, "OR", true]
```

The grouping of this source array if it were in an if statement would I believe be as follows:

```
(false || false || (false && false && false) || true) // true
```

And I would expect to output the following object which satifies the json-logic-js JS package:

```
const result = {
    'or': [
        false,
        false,
        {
            'and': [
                false,
                false,
                false,
            ]
        },
        true,
    ]
}
```

I have tried recursive functions and have been playing with the .reduce() method but as have yet been unable to find a solution. I struggle creating the object as I iterate over the source array. I have searched for similar answers here on SO but none seem to want the same result object structure as I do.

Comment: If it is indeed grouped like that, wouldn't the output be `{ or: [false, false, { and: [false, false, false] }, true] }`?

Comment: Ahh yes, you're right. Thank you. Have edited question.

Comment: I think the `and` elements should be `false` in your edit, right? Also, how are you deciding operator precedence?

Comment: Yes they should have been. Have updated question. Not using anything in particular, the source array is output from a different function in the program and so I'm just deciding the precedence based on what I think it should be. Should I be using something?

Comment: Not necessarily, I guess you can assume the ordinary and before or precedence. I'll try to write an answer, might take a bit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following solution. Hopefully the code is more or less self-explanatory:

```js
function process(arr) {
  const isBool = (x) => x === true || x === false;
  const prec = (x) => -["AND", "OR"].indexOf(x);

  // Convert infix -> postfix
  const postfix = [];
  const ops = [];
  for (const x of arr) {
    if (!isBool(x)) {
      const prev = ops[ops.length - 1];
      if (prev === undefined || prec(x) > prec(prev)) {
        ops.push(x);
      } else {
        while (ops.length > 0 && prec(x) < prec(ops[ops.length - 1])) {
          postfix.push(ops.pop());
        }
        ops.push(x);
      }
    } else {
      postfix.push(x);
    }
  }
  postfix.push(...ops.reverse());

  // Convert postfix -> output format
  const stack = [];
  for (const x of postfix) {
    if (!isBool(x)) {
      const op = x.toLowerCase();
      const prevs = [stack.pop(), stack.pop()];
      const obj = prevs.find((y) => !isBool(y) && y.hasOwnProperty(op));
      if (obj !== undefined) {
        const other = prevs.find((y) => y !== obj);
        obj[op].push(other);
        stack.push(obj);
      } else {
        stack.push({
          [op]: prevs,
        });
      }
    } else {
      stack.push(x);
    }
  }
  return stack[0];
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(process([false, "OR", false, "OR", false, "AND", false, "AND", false, "OR", true]), null, 2));
```

Comment: Hi, I'm testing this out at the moment but seems to be working well. Will be sure to mark as the answer soon.

Comment: Hi, quick question @iz_, is prec(x) > prec(prev) to check if previous is logic operator

Comment: It checks if the precedence of the current operator is greater than the precedence of the previous operator.

Comment: thanks, so is that something to do with making sure the precedence is correct? And if I wanted to NAND and NOR to the `prec` function, would I add them anywhere in the array or should I add them somewhere specific to maintain precedence?

Comment: It is part of the [infix to postfix algorithm](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stack-set-2-infix-to-postfix/). For precedence, you might even want to replace the array with an object like `{ AND: 2, OR: 1 }`. Also, it seems like the json logic library you want to use doesn't have `nand` or `nor`, so you might want to replace them with logically equivalent expressions with `and` and `or`.

Comment: Hi iz_, thanks again for your help on my problem. I have an interview later on today and I'm trying to understand more about what is happening in the process function you kindly wrote for me. Would you be able to tell me why infix to postifx was needed and maybe a little about what is going on in the process function as a whole? I'm studying your function now and reading the article that you linked to me but thought I'd reach out first in the hopes of a reply sooner :). Thank you iz_